# Update um para muitos Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, crud

Olá,
preciso de ajuda com um update usando entity framework e relacionamento um pra muitos. Acredito que seja algo bem básico, mas estou iniciando com EF e não consigo resolver o problema.

Entidades Artista e TelefoneArtista, sendo que um artista pode ter vários telefones.

```
 public class Artista
    {

        public Artista()
        {
            Telefones = new List<TelefoneArtista>();
        }
        public int ArtistaId { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TelefoneArtista> Telefones { get; set; }
    }

public class TelefoneArtista
    {

        public int TelefoneArtistaId { get; set; }
        public string Numero { get; set; }
        public int ArtistaId { get; set; }
        public virtual Artista Artista { get; set; }

    }
```

Como faço um update?

Tentei assim mas não da certo.

```
public void Update(Artista obj)
        {
            Db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
            Db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Desde já agradeço!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uso o seguinte algoritmo:

```
private async Task AtualizarTelefones(Artista artista)
{
    // Telefones Originais
    var telefonesOriginais = db.ArtistaTelefones.AsNoTracking().Where(at => at.ArtistaId == artista.ArtistaId).ToList();

    if (artista.ArtistaTelefones != null)
    {
        // Telefones Excluídos
        foreach (var telefoneOriginal in telefonesOriginais)
        {
            if (!artista.ArtistaTelefones.Any(rt => rt.ArtistaTelefoneId == telefoneOriginal.ArtistaTelefoneId))
            {
                var telefoneExcluido = db.ArtistaTelefones.Single(rt => rt.ArtistaTelefoneId == telefoneOriginal.ArtistaTelefoneId);
                db.ArtistaTelefones.Remove(telefoneExcluido);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }

        // Telefones Inseridos ou Alterados
        foreach (var telefone in artista.ArtistaTelefones)
        {
            if (!telefonesOriginais.Any(rt => rt.ArtistaTelefoneId == telefone.ArtistaTelefoneId))
            {
                // Telefone não existe ainda. Inserir.
                telefone.ArtistaId = artista.ArtistaId;
                db.ArtistaTelefones.Add(telefone);
            }
            else
            {
                // Telefone já existe. Marcar como alterado.
                db.Entry(telefone).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
    public void Update(Artista obj)
    {
        await AtualizarTelefones(obj);
        Db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
        Db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Também estou aprendendo EF, o que `if (!artista.ArtistaTelefones.Any(rt => rt.ArtistaTelefoneId == telefoneOriginal.ArtistaTelefoneId))` Faz exatamente, procura se removeu algo da lista?

Comment: Este trecho verifica se não existe um elemento cujo `ArtistaTelefoneId` seja igual ao `ArtistaTelefoneId` que existia antes. Ou seja, que o elemento foi apagado em tela.

Comment: Additional information: Não é possível iniciar uma operação assíncrona agora. As operações assíncronas só podem ser iniciadas em um manipulador ou módulo assíncrono ou durante certos eventos no ciclo de vida da Página.

Comment: Você pode usar o código sincrono, se quiser. Só remover todos os `async` e `await` (incluindo `SaveChangesAsync`, mudar para `SaveChanges`).